# SQL view from another Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I want to create a view in a Database residing in `SQL Server Express 2008`.

The view will be take its data from table residing on another server `SQL Server 2008` on another machine in the same LAN.

My Question is if a must create a Linked Server for this goal and if it is possible to create a linked Server on `SQL Express`.

Are there any solutions without using a linked Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and Yes and No. 
See my answer here:
 
[Login failed for user sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009703/login-failed-for-user-sql/24014138#24014138)

To access table T_Users on database catalog Cor_Basic on server CORDB2005 with user ApertureWebServicesDE (on CORDB2005) and password MY_TOP_SECRET_PASSWORD you would use:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@srvproduct = 'OLE DB Provider for SQL'
   ,@provider = N'SQLNCLI'
   ,@datasrc = 'CORDB2005'
   ,@catalog = 'COR_Basic'

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'RemoteDB'
   ,@useself = false
   --,@locallogin = 'LocalIntegrationUser'
   ,@locallogin = NULL 
   ,@rmtuser = N'ApertureWebServicesDE'
   ,@rmtpassword = N'MY_TOP_SECRET_PASSWORD'
GO




SELECT * 
FROM RemoteDB.COR_Basic.dbo.T_Users
```